# What are the reason jQuery uploader does not work on live server?

Tags: jquery

I have use jquery File uploader it work on my localhost but does not work on live server ?
What are the possible reason that it does't work on live server.

I have download the plug-in form the url

http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: uploading service is not avaialabale for india i thought ??

Comment: Have you check link and got my question clear IF NOT OKAY  I say that I have upload plugin form above link When I run my plugin on localhost it work perfectly,but when I use plugin in live server is not work fine.

Answer (score 0):

my reputation is not enough to comment, by my expericence, to check whether the web application has the right to save file in dest directory, this is the usual reason that the problem only occurs on production server.

Comment: what is production server ?

Comment: production server means your live server. because localhost always has the right to save file on disk, the web app on live server won't have if you don't config security purview for it.

Comment: How can I check this that my server have right to save file and also how can I config this.

Comment: how to set web application purview depends on the operation system, the usual way is to add a logger on your server side code. the log will tell you whether the server side handler is successfully called, and catch all exception that occurs.